# Insert a document into a mongoDB database from javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm writing an application and need to insert a document into a mongoDB database.  This is the code I have in my reactJS application to execute the fetch to insert the document:

```
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
        console.log(myJSON);
        var url = "https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/test-db/collections/buildings?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxN2ZvobziWxyhxxxxxxxxxx";

        const options = { 
            method: 'POST', 
            data: myJSON, 
            headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) 
        };

        fetch( url, options)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {   
            console.log("returned data: ", myJson);                
        });
```

When I execute my application, and I look at the console.log(), I see the string that is being sent to mongoDB and I see the console.log() that says "returned data: null.

Then, I took the string from the console.log that was sent to mongoDB and I entered it into POSTMAN.  I set up POSTMAN to execute a POST and I entered into the Headers a key of Content-Type and a value of application/json.  When I send the request, I get a response and then I looked at the mongoDB database and verified that the document was inserted.

Why does the document not get inserted from the javascript fetch() when it does get inserted from POSTMAN?

Thank you.

Comment: With `fetch`, I believe the `data` field in the options object should be called `body`.

Comment: @sketchedin  You are 100% correct.  I changed data to body and the document got inserted.  Thank you so much!